# Why doesn't document.write output anything to the page?

Tags: javascript, document.write

The `document.write("*stuff here")` won't work at all for some reason. I've tried everything! capitalization, variables, nothing!

```
<!doctype html>
<body>
    <center>
        <script type="javascript">
            var A = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
            var B = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
            var C = A+B;
            var Input = document.getElementById('Input');
            document.write("stupid javascript");
            function answer() {
                if(Input == C) {
                    document.write('correct!!');
                }
                else {
                    document.write("Incorrect!");
                }
            }
            document.write("A + B")
        </script>
    <form Id="Input">
        <input type="text">
    </form>
    <form onsubmit="javascript:Answer">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the ; at the end of document.write("A + B").

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Semicolons aren't required in JavaScript, especially in this situation

Comment: @أنيسبوهاشم Since they're using the HTML5 doctype, the `type` attribute could be removed altogether

Comment: Is your problem that the answer function isn't being called?  your onsubmit should be onsubmit="javascript:answer();"

Comment: this `<script type="text/javascript">` or this `<script>` otherwise it will not work

Comment: Inline event handlers shouldn't have `javascript:` prefixed

Comment: There a couple of things wrong in your script: a) Wrong `type` declaration. b) You are calling `document.getElementById('Input')` before the element exists. c) `Answer !== answer`, JavaScript is case-sensitive. d) `onsubmit="javascript:Answer"` doesn't call the function, you are missing `()` after the function name. e) Submitting the form will reload the page immediately, so you likely wouldn't even see the output. [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) so that you can find the problems yourself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is not the right place to learn the basics of a programming language.

Comment: I recommend to read http://quirksmode.org/js/contents.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide.

Answer (score 2):

**Your script type isn't correct.**

`<script type="javascript">` is wrong...

`<script type="text/javascript">` is correct...

Comment: Note that `text/javascript` is obsolete now and should be `application/javascript`. However, IE will not allow `application/javascript` so, personally, I like to just not specify the type (as allowed in `HTML5`).

Comment: That's only *one* of the many things that are wrong, although it will at least show `stupid javascript A + B` then.

Comment: @FelixKling So true… I started to debug that but I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

What was wrong is
`<script type="javascript">`

It must be

`<script type="text/javascript">`

. To execute scripts immediately, you can add the following code after input:

```
<script>document.write('Javascript is not stupid')</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 'Answer' to 'answer' in the following line:

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:Answer">
```